# What is the story behind the famous Shiva linga of Amarnath, India?

Tags: shiva, temple, shiva-lingam, jyotirlinga

[image]

is considered to be one of the holiest shrines in Hinduism.

The cave is surrounded by snowy mountains.

Hundreds of thousands of Hindu devotees make an annual pilgrimage to the Amarnath cave on challenging mountainous terrain.

I want to know that what has been said in Hindu scriptures about Shiva linga of Amarnath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Essence of Amarnatha yatra Phala](http://kamakoti.org/kamakoti/details/Essence%20of%20Amarnatha%20yatra%20Phala.pdf) article which is based on **Bhringi Samhita of Skanda Purana**,

> Mritustaanagrasat sarvaan Devaabhi sa Vaasavaan,
>
> Devaste mrityunaa grastaavya kulaahyabhavam Priye/
>
> Sametya sharanam jaguh sharanyam Parameshwaram,
>
> Tushtuvuh parama preetyaa Shankarah tamonaashranam/
>
> - Mrityu tormented Devaas, headed by Indra, approached Parama Shiva for
>   refuge and protection and appealed as follows to the ever merciful
>   Shiva.
>
> Namo niyati rupaaya tatwarupayate namah,
>
> Mahattwaaya Devaaya Sukshma Tatwaayate namah/
>
> Namomritaaya Devaaya Namomrita swarupine,
>
> Mrityunjayaaya Devaaya bhuyo bhuyo namo namah/
>
> - Our prayers to you Niyati Rupa, Tatwa Rupa, Mahattatwa, Sukshma
>   Tatwa, Amrita Rupa, Amrita Swarupine, Mrithyunjaya, Maha Deva, Bhuyo
>   bhuyo namyah. As the delegation of Devaas led by Indra commended as
>   above, Maha Deva was pleased and on his enquiry, Indra explained about
>   the constant threats posed by Mrityu to all of them:
>
> Yatah sa mrityur nashyayenno seveccha balena hi,
>
> Tatkurushwa Maha Deva bhaiktaanaamaarti naashana/
>
> - Devadhideva! Do kindly show us a way out from the strangle hold of
>   Mrityu so that it should not overcome us and torment us; kindly ensure
>   that the desperation and constant threat to your Bhaktas like us be
>   terminated forthwith.
>
> Shrutwaa Deva vachah soumyam Maheshah pratyuvaacha taan,
>
> Mrityupaayam karishyaami sahadhwam kshanamuttamaah/
>
> - Maha Deva realised the gravity of the problem and assured Devas of a solution soon
>
> Griheetwaa shirastatra Haraschandra kalaam swayam,
>
> Sampeedyav Devaanna vadanmrithyu bheshaja peedanaat/
>
> Yaa nisrutaa chaiva tathaa dharaa seetatraa paarmika Priye,
>
> Sauva bhutaa nede punyaa naamnaavaih Amaravati/
>
> Ye bindavaschayutaa Devi Shariremrita bindavah,
>
> Te bhasma rupataam prapyachyuscheshanataam gataah/
>
> - Bhagavan himself adjusted the Chandra Kala on his head and pulled out a flow of Sacred River named Amaravati from his body. The River
>   materialised into chilled cool drops and as many drops of Amrita that
>   flowed turned out to take the shape of a hallowed Linga decorated with
>   Bhasma and that indeed was the Amara Natha Maha Deva Himself).
>
> Premaateshaam Maha Devi Shivopidravataamagaat,
>
> te drushtwaatu Shivam tatra dravibhutam Maheshwari/
>
> - This was how Maha Deva got melted from the desperate cries of Devas to
>   save themselves from the clutches of Mrityu (**That indeed was the
>   Origin of Amara Naatha Linga!**).

**Further Readings:**

Many articles listed [here](http://www.koausa.org/amarnath/index.html) also have some information from scriptures or early texts on the Amarnath Linga.